# getting the size of a content box with javascriptHey

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the width of my content box with the following comand:

```
var box = document.getElementById('player');
var boxSize = box.clientWidth;
```

It seems to return something. When I alert it it gives out a number. But it still throws the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null
```

What is happening here?

Comment: perhaps your code is running before the element with ID has been rendered ... is the script above or below the element with that ID in the html document?

Comment: Do you gave `#player` element in DOM and it's loaded?

Comment: @Justinas - it's not `#player`, it's just `id="player"`

Comment: @JaromandaX My javascript is called at the end of the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var box = document.getElementById('player');
if(box){
  var boxSize = box.offsetWidth;
}
```

Comment: How does it solves `Cannot read property of null`?

Comment: offsetWidth gives the same error.

Comment: thanks. if(box) also works with 
var boxSize = box.clientWidth;